# UnintentionalCodeFirstException in ASP.NET MVC Applicatoin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application (Visual Basic) that keeps getting an "UnintentionalCodeFirstException" when I try to add a new "record" to the DB.

Here is some of the pertaining code:

From the controller:

```
Namespace mvc
    Public Class ProjectsController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As ProjectContext = New ProjectContext
```

From the model:

```
Public Class ProjectContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
    End Sub

    Public Property Projects() As DbSet(Of Project)
End Class
```

From Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mvc-20140124124050;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mvc-20140124124050.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I suspect that I have a problem w/the connection string?

I am not too sure if the application was developed using Code or Data First model.  Furthermore I am not completely sure that the Entity Framework was utilized (or perhaps it is but since I am new to ASP.NET MVC development, I am not able to provide a concrete claim about this).

The exception is thrown on the Add method:

```
<HttpPost()>
        Function Create(project As Project) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Projects.Add(project)
```

Comment: Why does your example show a DbSet of FooMovies but your Database definition only has Projects?

Comment: Cut-n-paste error.  Here is the ACTUAL code wherein the exception is thrown by the Add() method.

        <HttpPost()>
        Function Create(project As Project) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Projects.Add(project)
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")

Comment: The "Accounts" Model also contains some code that refers to the DB:

Public Class UsersContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
    End Sub

    Public Property UserProfiles As DbSet(Of UserProfile)
End Class

Comment: The DB contains a table for "Users" which DOES get updated when a new user is registered (the functionality for this was created as part of the solution when first created. Meaning this is not code that the developers put in place).

Comment: The "Users" table is updated as a result of this code:

<HttpPost()> _
    <AllowAnonymous()> _
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()> _
    Public Function Register(ByVal model As RegisterModel) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            ' Attempt to register the user
            Try
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password)
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password)

So why does the connection to the DB's "Users" table exist for this function BUT not when the addition of a new "Project" is attempted?

Comment: Edit your post, it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: How exactly do I paste or format it so that the code is formatted for readability? It keeps getting posted as one contiguous string.

Comment: You're not listening.  EDIT your post.  Do not keep posting in comments.